# Увеличивать число a на n раз, но чтобы оно не увеличилось больше заданого максимума

Tags: javascript

есть переменая а которая припустим не должна быть больше 5-ти. Число n рандомно будет подбираться в диапазоне 0 - 5. Мне нужно увеличивать число а на n, но чтобы не больше 5-ти, если же число увеличит больше, начинать с нуля и добавлять остаток. Например:

```
a = 3;
n = 4;
res = a + n = 3 + 4 = 1
```

(поскольку счет идет с нуля).
еще
`res = 4 + 5 = 3`.

Comment: `res = (a + n) % 6;`

Comment: @yaant, спасибо, самое простое и елегантное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сформулировано очень непонятно, но предположу, что требуется что-то типа:

```js
const min = 0;
const max = 5;
const getRandomInt = ( min, max ) => Math.round(Math.random() * max) + min;
const getNum = () => {
  const a = getRandomInt(min, max);
  const n = getRandomInt(min, max);
  const sum = a + n;
  const res = sum > max ? sum - max - 1 : sum;
  
  console.log(`res = a + n = ${a} + ${n} = ${res}`);
  
  return res;
};

getNum();
getNum();
getNum();
getNum();
getNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Увеличить a на n. Вычитать 5 из результата до тех пор, пока результат не станет меньше 5. Потом подумать и вместо циклов вычитания взять остаток от деления на 5.

Comment: Ход мысли правильный, добавьте код к ответу для наглядности, так будет лучше)

Comment: Немного ошибся. Надо было взять остаток от деления на 6. Код на Delphi:
<code>
const
  constN: array of Integer = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var
  VarA: Integer;
  VarN: Integer;
  VarR: Integer;
begin
  for VarA:= 0 to 5 do
    for VarN in constN do begin
      VarR:= (VarA + VarN) mod 6;
      ListBox.Items.Append('A=' + VarA.ToString + ', N=' + VarN.ToString + ', res=' + VarR.ToString);
    end;
end;
</code>
Собственно @yaant уже дал этот ответ. Такая простая операция гораздо лучше выполнения условных операторов.

Answer (score -2):

```
    function random(min,max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+min);
    }
    var a=random(0,5);
    var n=random(0,5):
    var result=a*n;
if(n>1&&a>0){
    while(result<5){
    result=result*n;
    }
}
    while(result>5){
    result=result-5;
    }
```

Comment: Вы свой код запустить пытались? Попытался его отредактировать, не вышло, я честно пытался, но слишком много ошибок, что бы отредактировать, нужно на 40% переписать.

Comment: теперь код рабочий

Comment: Вы пишете код в среде где его невозможно проверить? Даже не запуская его, можно понять, что он уйдет в бесконечный цикл, так как в первом же `while` умножение будет всегда происходить на 0 и `result<5` будет всегда верным.

Comment: фикс. теперь первый while запускается только если n больше 1

Comment: Серьёзно, прежде чем давать ответ, убедитесь, что ваш код хотя бы работает, а лучше что бы он выполнял задачу хотя бы в 50% случаев ... Если `a` будет 0, `result` тоже будет 0, получаем ту же проблему. Если даже так не случится, код все равно делает что-то странное (может вы как-то иначе задачу поняли, тогда проясните, что именно он делает)